# Local branch not deleted in git

Tags: git, github

I want to delete local branch from git. It shows the delete message but actually it is not deleted. the code is written as follows:
[I have no idea what is going on this image. Please help me to delete remove-ipsum from local git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dp5T.png)

```
git branch -a
git checkout master
git branch -d remove-ipsum
```

it shows the deletation message as : **Deleted branch remove-ipsum (was 870afb1).**

```
git branch -a
```

but still displaying this branch.

Why this is happens? any solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**In short** : No problem to solve, your local branch has been deleted successfully.

---

**Why?**

Since you got the deletion confirmation message, we now know that the *local* version of that branch has successfully been deleted.

But `git branch -a` displays not only local branches, it also lists *remote-tracking* branches. So unless the branch was never pushed/pulled, it has a remote-tracking counterpart which hasn't been pruned yet.

---

**So what's left to do?**

Either the branch still exists remotely for good reasons, or you can also delete it with

```
git push <remoteName> :<branchName>
```

(be sure to notice the space before the "`:`", this is very different from `<remoteName>:<branchName>`)

or (alternative syntax for completion, but their effect is identical)

```
git push --delete <remoteName> <branchName>
```

Warning though, since there's no confirmation on this step : it *will* delete the branch no matter what, merged or not.

---

**Finally**

At this point, both local and remote versions of the branch are gone, and you will **still** have the branch show up in `git branch -a` output. What?! Why?

Because as we mentioned above, the *remote-tracking* branch, being a local copy of the remote branch (for off-line comparison's sake), hasn't been deleted neither by your first command nor by the one I suggested to you for the remote branch.

So, to prune it from your remote-tracking branches list, now that you've deleted the remote counterpart, you can

```
git fetch --prune
```

and it won't show up in `git branch -a` output any more.

Comment: Oh thanks !! it really working. But i dont understand, what git fetch --prune do? could you explain little more what does that mean ?

Comment: @Tekson This is why I added last paragraph, but I guess I should have added the link to the doc, check [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---prune). In shirt it checks which refs are gone on the remote, and deletes corresponding remote-tracking branches.